# The affine special linear group acts doubly transitive

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, linear-transformations, group-actions

Let $F$ be a field and $d \ge 2$. Denote by $ASL_d(F)$ the *affine special linear group*, i.e. the group of all transformation on $F^d$ with $t_{A,v}(u) = Au + v$ and $\det A = 1$. I want to show that this group is $2$-transitive (also called doubly transitive) on the points from $F^d$. For this I have to show that for $x,y, x', y'$ with $x \ne y$ and $x' \ne y'$ I can find an element $t_{A,v} \in ASL_d(F)$ such that
$$
 x' = t_{A,v}(x) = Ax + v \qquad\mbox{and}\qquad
 y' = t_{A,v}(y) = Ay + v.
$$
Any ideas or hints how to solve this?

I have solved it in the case $d = 2$ by a cumbersome solution of the equations involved, with the restriction on the determinant for $d = 2$ with the above I have five equations and six unknows (the elements of the matrix and of the translation vector $v$), so this could be solved. But my solution is quite messy and involves a lot of rearrangemnt and equation handling, so any short solution would be preferred?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you notice that you must have $$\vec{x^\prime y^\prime}  = A. \vec{xy}.$$ As $x^\prime \neq y^\prime$ and $x \neq y$, both vectors $e_1=\vec{xy}$ and $e_1^\prime=\vec{x^\prime y^\prime}$ are non zero.

Complete $\{e_1\}$ and $\{e_1^\prime\}$ into basis $\mathcal B=(e_1, \dots ,e_d)$ and $\mathcal B^\prime=(e_1^\prime, \dots ,e_d^\prime)$ of your associated vector space that I name $E$. You can find a linear map $A$ that transform $\mathcal B$ into $\mathcal B^\prime$, hence $\det A \neq 0$. Moreover, by changing $e_d^\prime$ into $\frac{e_d^\prime}{\det A}$ (which is possible as you supposed $d \ge 2$), you can even get $A$ such that $\det A=1$.

Finally, you compute $v=y-A.x$.

Comment: You mean $v := y - Ay = x - Ax$? Also I do not get how the determinant gets transformed, for example if $d = 2$ and I have $e_1' = Ae_1, e_2' = Ae_2$ and I choose a matrix $B$ such that $e_1' = Be_1$ and $\frac{e_2'}{\det A} = Be_2$, why does it follows that $\det B = 1$?

Comment: Regarding $v$, yes this is what I mean. $B$ in your comment has $\det B =1/\det A$. So you get a matrix with determinant equal to $1$ by the rule of multiplication of the determinants.

Answer (score 7):

It is easy to show the group is one-transitive.  Once you have done this, you can take any vector (the 0 vector is easy to work with), and show that the stabilizer of that vector is transitive on the other vectors (this is an equivalent way to show 2-transitivity).  (Hint: the stabilizer of the 0 vector is ${\rm SL}_{d}(F)$).

If you would rather prove this directly by showing any pair $(x,y)$ can be mapped to any other pair $(x^{\prime}, y^{\prime})$, you can think of transforming in several steps using several group elements.  Find a $g_{1}$ mapping $x$ to $0$ and $y$ to $y-x$, a $g_{2}$ mapping $0$ to $0$ and $y-x$ to $y^{\prime}-x^{\prime}$, and then a $g_{3}$ mapping $0$ to $x^{\prime}$ and $y^{\prime} - x^{\prime}$ to $y^{\prime}$.  Thinking of it in this sequence should let you guarantee the existence of a mapping $g_{3}(g_{2}(g_{1})))$ from $(x,y)$ to $(x^{\prime}, y^{\prime})$.

Comment: Concerning your explanation as a series of transformations, mapping $(x,y)$ to $(0, (y-x))$ involves also one element mapping four points onto each other, i.e. $x$ to $0$ and $y$ to $y-x$, so why does this follows from $1$-transitivity??

Comment: @Stefan The second paragraph is if you want to do it without using one-transitivity.  I am thinking of mapping $(x,y)$ to $(x^{\prime}, y^{\prime})$ using a composition of several group elements.  For example, $t_{I,-x}$ will map $x$ to $0$ and $y$ to $y-x$.